# Add timestamp to grails requests

Tags: grails

I want to add a timestamp to one of my requests in grails. How would I go about this.
The reason for timestamp at the end of the url is to prevent caching in browser.

```
class UrlMappings {
  static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }
    "/"(controller: "main")
    "/build/onetime/place"(controller: "main", action: "placeInAction")
}
```

I want to add the timestamp to just this one

```
"/build/onetime/place"(controller: "main", action: "placeInAction")
```

Comment: What actually do you mean by timestamp? Elaborating an use case will be useful.

Comment: Your question is very unclear... To get a relevant answer, you must be able to explain clearly what your problem is.

Comment: Timestamp is usually used at the end of a url to prevent caching in browsers.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to add the timestamp to avoid caching, You don't need to map it in `UrlMapping`, just append it to the url as a query parameter.

Have a look at this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/256597/172324) to get a clear picture.